# Calculating the correct pitch

Tags: c#, math, trigonometry

```
        public double GetPitchToFace(double Z2, double Z1, double X2, double X1)
    {            
        double Arc;
        Arc = Math.Atan2(Z2 - Z1, X2 - X1);
        return Arc;
    }
```

I am attempting to work out the correct pitch in order to "face" a specific point.

Using Atan2 (as seen above) seems to return the correct values however in-game the pitch system seems to work rather strangely.

Instead of increasing anti-clockwise from 0 radian all the way back to 6.2 it starts from 0 up to 3 radian then jumps down to -3 radian and works its way back to 0 once again.

[image: Example of Pitch]

Hopefully you can understand the bad drawing example above.

I need a way to convert from that strange pitch / radian system to the standard 0 - 6.2 radians in order to return a correct pitch.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `Math.Atan2` method returns the angle *θ* (in radians) such that *-π ≤ θ ≤ π* it will yield negative values when the input point is in the third or fourth quadrant.

To return only positive values (i.e. *0 ≤ θ ≤ 2π*) one can use simple mathematics. Since *2π* is a full rotation you can add that whenever the `Math.Atan2` method returns a negative value. This will only give you values in your wanted range.

```
 public double GetPitchToFace(double Z2, double Z1, double X2, double X1)
    {            
        double Arc;
        double theta = Math.Atan2(Z2 - Z1, X2 - X1);
        Arc = (theta >= 0) ? theta : (2*Math.PI + theta);
        return Arc;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I am not sure why I never thought of that.

I see now my issue deepens a little, I find that I am often returning the inverse angle. In a perfect world I'd have a pitch between 90 and 270 degrees as I only need to pitch up or down towards a point. 

Yet, I see it returning 300++ basically resulting the player / object flipping upside down.