# ATan2 for pitch on Right-handed coordinate system

Tags: c#, math, trigonometry

```
        public double GetPitchToFace(double Z2, double Z1, double X2, double X1)
    {            
        double Arc;
        Arc = Math.Atan2(Z2 - Z1, X2 - X1);
        Arc = (Arc >= 0) ? Arc+Math.PI : (2 * Math.PI + Arc);      
        return Arc;
    }
```

I am attempting to calculate the correct pitch of a player in-game in order to face and travel to a waypoint.

It might be worth noting that the games coordinate system is Right-Handed.

I've confirmed that ATan2 is receiving the correct values yet the return value is incorrect.

It seems to be returning a downward pitch despite the waypoint being above the player. Yet other times it returns the seemingly correct pitch - I suspect this might have something to do when the point / player shift quadrants ?

(Minor side note - the reason I am 2 * Math.PI if Arc is >= 0 is simply the way the game stores and manages player pitch more info can be found here :
[Pitch-Ingame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72170632/calculating-the-correct-pitch/72171265#72171265)
)

Here is an example of the above manually calculated :

```
Atan2(Z2 - Z1, X2 - X1)
Arc = Atan2(179.7 - 157.9, -3457.1-(-3432.1))
Arc = Atan2(21.7,-25.3)
Arc = 2.4 Radians
Arc = Arc + PI (without adding PI we return 137.51 degrees this is the opposite angle I need so I add PI to flip it to the correct side or add 180 degrees)
Arc = 5.5 Radians
Arc = 315,127 Degrees (this is a downwards trend from the point meaning we still miss the end point)
```

Here is the really bad plot of the above points[image: Example of points]

Please keep in mind that the points are plotted such as X,Z not X,Y

Comment: Could you edit your question and add a few examples with input values, expected result and actual result?

Comment: When you do `ATan2(y2-y1, x2-x1)`, you get the angle of the vector from `(x1, x2)` to `(y1, y2)`. _This is already what you seem to be looking for!_ Since `Atan2` returns a value between `-pi` and `pi`, you need to add `2pi` _only when the returned value is `< 0`!_ You don't need to add the `pi` when the value is `>= 0`. By adding `pi`, you are getting the angle _from_ `(x2, y2)` to `(x1, y1)`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Yes, but if I don't add PI when >= 0 it seems to return the incorrect value - in other words the outer pitch. So if I were to set that returned pitch to the player or object it would be upside down. Such that if I wanted to move the player towards the object it would have to travel backwards (because it's upside down) I suspect this result has something to do with the fact that the coordinate system is right-handed.

Comment: You want the angle at which the `Player` point needs to travel to reach the `Waypoint` point, correct? That is what you get from Markus's answer to your previous question. I don't quite understand what you mean by "outer pitch".

Comment: After the edit: So you set the rotation to 2.4rad and the player faced _away_ from the waypoint? That would seem to indicate that your game engine uses a funky coordinate system, or that your player graphic isn't aligned with the coordinate system. Set the rotation to progressively larger values from 0 to 2pi and observe (1) which direction your player faces when the rotation is zero and (2) which direction your player turns as you increase the rotation. The standard coordinate system _is_ right-handed, with the horizontal axis pointing to the right and the vertical axis pointing upwards.